# Allowing HTTP Header Content Type */* in Azure WAF Rules

Tags: azure, content-type, http-status-code-403, azure-application-gateway, azure-waf

I am trying to call the Azure-hosted API endpoint using a 3rd party application. Application sends the HTTP request with the header values `ContentType = "*/*";`

Azure Application Gateway WAF blocks the request showing the below diagnostics logs.

I am aware that, I can add an `exclusion` in the `Web Application Firewall` settings, however, I am not able to extract the `Request Header Name` since the logs do not show the value due to the wildcard(`ContentType = "*/*";`) content type sent by the 3rd party app.

I added the below rule, but it is still blocking the request.
[image: Rule 1]

How can I allow the request via the AGW?

Please find the logs below.

[image: Log 1]
[image: Log 2]
[image: Log 3]

Thanks in advance.